# Setting up these Tortoise SVN commit hooks

Tags: linux, windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to set up a commit hook that will subsequently upload source files from a Windows environment to a Linux server, which is not the same as Linux server running SVN.

I'm familiar with setting up client side hooks, but not sure what the script should be like.

I'm not really sure the easiest way to go about this. I'm thinking a Windows script that will run a copy command that can do this sort of thing. My entire group would use it so the script would have to be located on a Windows NFS. Ideas?

Comment: Unless you want this to be dependent upon proper client configuration (always a risky proposition), you need this to be a server-side hook script, not a TortoiseSVN client-side hook.

Comment: @alroc - wrong, handling real files in WC is easier, than repository-data

Comment: You can still have a WC on the server that a post-commit hook works with. The point is, you cannot depend upon a client-side hook script in TSVN because there's no guarantee that all users will use TSVN, nor that they won't mess with the script.

Answer (score 0):

> not sure what the script should be like

Client-side (as server-side) hook is any program, which can be executed on this host. Single difference between these type of hooks is location, where program is executed - clent-side hooks of TortoiseSVN will run on developer's host with Working Copy

Your script must be non-interactive set of operations, which will perform needed operation (ssh or ftp to target host, upload files) - can't see any problem here (except one - FTPing a bundle of /random/ files is always a big headache)

Comment: Do you have an idea the easiest program to use, run from Windows, that can perform the copy? Maybe there is already an existing Windows command that comes with Windows 7? Was hoping to avoid downloading a script somewhere, putting it on a Windows share, and asking everyone to keep the shortcut somewhere on their machine.

Comment: @Wes - "It depends". Do you have shell-access to target or only FTP|<someanothertype>? SSH-upload is `scp` (part of Putty), FTP-upload - NCFTP (ncftpput part), used inside trivial bat-file

Comment: I'll take a look at the different possibilities and let you guys know which one I go with and why. Thanks